# Writing HyperLogLog Sketches from Apache Spark To Trino

Tags: apache-spark, trino, hyperloglog

I'm attempting to generate aggregate HLL sketches in a Scala Spark job and push the data to a varbinary in Trino for dashboard aggregations.

I'm using the spark-alchemy library to generate the sketches in Spark, but continue to run into compatibility issues when running the `cardinality` function in Trino. Specifically, the error

`Cannot deserialize HyperLogLog`

Trino uses the HLL implementation from airlift, but bringing that library in and writing UDFs around that implementation seems awfully cumbersome. Is there a more streamline way to obtain interoperability between Spark HLL and Trino HLL?